Working with Value Labels and numerical values in SPSS to create meaningful regressions
I am writing my master thesis on the effect of AI surveillance on the relationship between locations and the user perception of safety and privacy. I created a survey that asked respondents safe and unsafe locations (on a percentage scale). Then I asked questions about the user perception of privacy and safety on a 5 point scale. In SPSS, these questions are grouped into value labels (1: strong increase, 2: increase, 3: unaltered, 4: decrease, 5: strong decrease). I am wondering how I can work with these variables to make meaningful regressions that I can work with.

Welcome to CrossValidated.  Can you say specifically where you are stuck?

The problem is that the user perception of privacy and safety (the Likert scale is my dependent variable). So any regression I try does not make sense regarding the output

I'm not sure if this is more a programming question (how to do this in SPSS) or a statistics question (which model to use). I have answered your statistics question, but this question may be closed if your question is more about programming in SPSS.

If the issue is that your have word strings as values (i.e. the responses are literally coded as "increase", "unaltered" etc.,) you can use SPSS command "Recode into different variables" to change them into numbers. Or syntax with RECODE.

Probably the most straight-forward application I can think of for this sort of problem is an ordinal logistic regression, which luckily is an option for SPSS since you are using that software. The response is usually an ordered category in these models, and Likert scale typically exhibits this sort of behavior.
